# How can I save GAS to my own source repository?

Tags: google-apps-script

GAS is using its own on-line editor spreadsheets,forms,script
but to store each version of my edits i'm keeping a duplicate source repository,
and to do this i laboriously "select all"+copy for each file in the GAS
editor and "select all"+paste in my external file.

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: How about a method using Google Drive API? You can download scripts from Google Drive using Drive API. You can import the downloaded scripts to your repository. This process can be executed automatically by a script. You can see about Google Drive API at here. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

Comment: How about creating a [standalone scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone), a standalone script is any script that is not bound to a Google Sheets, Docs, or Forms file or Google Sites. These scripts appear among your files on Google Drive. The easiest way to create a standalone script is to visit [script.google.com](https://script.google.com). Also, you can create this script in the Drive API itself. For more information, check this [thread](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/managing_projects#creating-a-project-from-google-drive). Hope this info helps you.

Comment: hmm thats because we don't know where embedded scripts are stored right? I'm further complicated this by using scripts in Google Sites, no idea where they are accessible elsewhere.....I must admit i do manage to confuse myself here with where the script is.........maybe using Google sites app scripts need to be deprecated?
so i need to write code to pull the files from Gdrive, but still doesn't help with embedded scripts......

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Github there is a really nice chrome extension that adds Github functionality to the IDE.

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo

Check out the project README on setup options and how to do things like create directories.

> https://github.com/leonhartX/gas-github

Comment: and says it works with bound ("embedded) scripts! well someone has the secret source of how to get them scripts....
anyhow thanks

Comment: Yea the extension doesn't use the IO API. It uses the the GWT-RPC protocol used by google in the IDE. It isn't public and there is no documentation, but after taking a look at the network traffic its pretty simple to do a replay on it.  The only down side is that when ever there is a IDE rebuild version numbers get bumped and you have to go back and reflect those in the code.

Comment: @SpencerEaston yes the RPC version up is really a headache, I'm now trying something to auto detect the change.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse, rather than the online editor, you can then keep copies locally and sync them with your preferred repository.

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/apps_script

Comment: ok thanks, looks interesting, but again it only works with standalone scripts right?

Comment: Yes - sadly that's true. It's best for standalone script projects.